# Hacer una búsqueda en Laravel con where

Tags: laravel, where

Realice la siguiente consulta con los siguientes valores de búsqueda que el usuario envía por `POST` a mi controller, supongamos que lo que envío es esto que pongo de ejemplo:

`$input['no_lote'] = null; $input['h_clinica'] = cmg 20;`

Supongamos que el usuario ingreso en el input `h_clinica` y dejó `no_lote` vacío y ejecutó la búsqueda . En mi Controller la consulta es la siguiente:

```
`$valores = Model::where('no_lote', $input['no_lote'] )->orWhere('historia_clinica', $input['h_clinica'])->get();
```

Pero me devuelve varios elementos que no contienen `h_clincia` con ese valor que estoy pasando a la consulta. Por que puede ser este problema? Aclaro que `n_lote` no es nulo en ninguno de mis elementos en la base de datos

Comment: Si deseas que se busque por null, debes usar `whereNull('no_lote')` y ademas la variable h_clinica debe estar entre comillas `'cmg 20'`

Comment: Edite la pregunta para mayor comprensión